# animate conatiner while changing screen flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I[image: this is my code and picture] want to animate a container(upcoming task container),when go back to home screen from tasks screen I tried using Animated container but not working any help???

Answer (score 0):

Use the **AnimatedContainer** widget for this. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI-8QHpGIP4) is the video explanation from Flutter Devs, about how to do it.